# Steam Play Game (Offline) that is Partially Updated

Tags: steam, space-engineers

Not sure if there is somewhere else to post this.

There is a game that has such a big update I can't download it all at once, but I want to do it in bits. But I also want to play the game offline. I was wondering if I start updating a game then pause it, then run Steam and the game in offline mode, will it delete or have to restart the entire update when Steam is back online? Thanks

EDIT: The game is Space Engineers, so you might know just how frequently it is updated.

Comment: It will help to know what game specifically you're referring to, as not every game is the same on Steam

Comment: Space Engineers